# Escape single quote in string and interpolate that string into another string with unescaped single quotes

Tags: ruby, string, curl, escaping

Trying to get a curl call to work

Here's the ruby code

```
msg = "john's message"

@body = %Q|{"body":{"version":1,"type":"doc","content":[{"type":"paragraph","content":[{"type":"text","text":"#{msg}"}]}]}}|.gsub("'"){"\\'"}

puts @body

curl_call = %Q|curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx' -d '#{@body}' --url 'https://api.atlassian.com/site/xxxx/conversation/xxxx/message'|

puts curl_call

system(curl_call)
```

This is the error: `sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

Open to suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you replace `'` by unicode encoded (`\u0027`), then it works:

```
.gsub("'", "\u0027")
```

Comment: I doesn't work when I do it straight forward. Can you explain how it works?

Comment: My answer didn't work? I've just tested it out and it worked perfectly :(